# why am I getting a metawhere join dependency error in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, meta-where

I get a metawhere join dependency error with the following:

```
@companies_user = Company.joins(:contact).where(:contact => {:user_id => current_user.id}).uniq
```

Company has_many contacts

In other words, every Contact has a method company_id

I want to show those companies (only one) where the contacts have a user_id equal to that of the user doing the search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if your company has many contacts then you should include `contacts` not `contact`

```
@companies_user = Company.joins(:contacts).where(:contacts => {:user_id => current_user.id}).uniq
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not doing it this way?

```
current_user.contact.companies
```

Then you can use .limit to only fetch one...

Comment: how does this work, it would list only the companies once if I use .limit?